# GL_PROJECTION and GL_MODELVIEW in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to port some legacy OpenGL 1.x code to WebGL / Three.JS:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(...)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(...)
// rest of rendering
```

I am setting my Three.JS camera's projection like so (note that I do not want to use a `PerspectiveCamera`, my projection matrix is pre-calculated):

```
var camera = new THREE.Camera()
camera.projectionMatrix.fromArray(...)
```

And I am setting my Three.JS camera's pose like so:

```
var mat = new THREE.Matrix4();
mat.fromArray(...);
mat.decompose(camera.position, camera.quaternion, camera.scale);
camera.updateMatrix();
scene.updateMatrixWorld(true);
```

I am testing this with the following:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 35, 35);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffff00});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
camera.add(mesh);
mesh.position.set(0, 0, -40); // fix in front of the camera
scene.add(mesh);
```

I can see that my camera's pose is being set correctly (by logging it), but nothing is being rendered to the screen. Am I setting the projection matrix incorrectly?

Comment: @Rabbid76 projection matrix is calculated off of a calibrated camera with OpenCV. The actual implementation is here: http://docs.ros.org/fuerte/api/pangolin_wrapper/html/display_8cpp_source.html#l01201

Comment: @Sepehr Well, for one thing, you need to do this, instead: `camera.add( mesh ); scene.add( camera );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be my `modelView` matrix. This is how I ported my legacy code to ThreeJS:

```
// OpenGL 1.x code
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(projectionMatrix)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(modelViewMatrix)

// ThreeJS code
/* GL_PROJECTION matrix can be directly applied here */
camera = new THREE.Camera()
camera.projectionMatrix.copy(projectionMatrix)

/* GL_MODELVIEW should be inverted first */
modelViewMatrix.getInverse(modelViewMatrix)
modelViewMatrix.decompose(camera.position, camera.quaternion, camera.scale)
```

Looking at [ThreeJS WebGL renderer source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/e9d6b1e1716cf56cedea7e9fc95adabfd58aea5b/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L1383), ThreeJS' `modelViewMatrix` is calculated by multiplying camera's `matrixWorldInverse` into object's matrix.

`Matrix4`'s `decompose` updates camera's `matrixWorld`, hence the actual matrix used in model-view calculation ends up inverted.

**EDIT:** here's a plug and play ThreeJS camera to use in this scenario:

```
/**
 * @author Sepehr Laal
 * @file OpenGLCamera.js
 */

function OpenGLCamera () {

  THREE.Camera.call(this)

  this.type = 'OpenGLCamera'
}

OpenGLCamera.prototype = Object.assign(Object.create(THREE.Camera.prototype), {

  constructor: OpenGLCamera,

  isOpenGLCamera: true,

  /*
   * Equivalent to OpenGL 1.x:
   * glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   * glLoadMatrixf(...)
   */
  setProjectionFromArray: function (arr) {

    this.projectionMatrix.fromArray(arr)

  },

  /*
   * Equivalent to OpenGL 1.x:
   * glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   * glLoadMatrixf(...)
   */
  setModelViewFromArray: function () {

    var m = new THREE.Matrix4();

    return function (arr) {
      m.fromArray(arr)
      m.getInverse(m)
      m.decompose(this.position, this.quaternion, this.scale)
    };

  }()

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your projection matrix is correct? (and as Sepehr Well pointed out, are you adding the camera to the scene?)

There are a few places that updateProjectionMatrix is called in the camera code, which will overwrite your matrix, so I'd put a break point in there to see if it is doing that.

Comment: I am pretty sure my matrix is correct, since it works just fine in the OpenGL 1.x code. Camera is added to the scene (I can see it in `camera.parent`)

Comment: Can you render with a regular perspective or ortho matrix and see your  geometry?

Comment: yep. I posted an answer to my question. `modeView` matrix needed to be inverted first.